# Setting view on mapview based on gps coordinates

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-location

I'm trying to set the bounds on the mapview that I'm working with, so I'm always centered a certain way, and I can also see a full set of information based on the view. Basically I'll get a GPS coordinate for the center point, and then I'll get another value, say .9, which is the difference in the x/y of the current GPS spot that needs to be present in the current view. Example

Center-point: 37.777125, -12.2419644 (San Francisco)

Difference: .9

So the view would need to be

```
Top-Left: 36.877125, -13.1419644
Bottom-Right: 38.677125, -11.3419644
```

Is there a way to set the map view's bounds in this way?

Comment: are you trying to zoom your mapView to this rect? Or you are trying to actually set mapView dimensions (i.e. resize your mapView)? Also I did not get where your `Top-Left` and `Bottom-Right` values came from... How did you calculate them?

Comment: Zoom map to this rect. Obviously it won't work with my exact example, because the view cannot be square, but I need the map to zoom and show those dimensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is. There is an interface in mapView's controller - `zoomToSpan(long, long)`.
What you need is to do the following:

```
long latSpan = Math.abs(startLat - endLat);
long lonSpan =  Math.abs(startLon - endLon);

mapView.getController().zoomToSpan(latSpan, lonSpan);
```

Where `startLat`, `endLat`, `startLon`, `endLon` - your calculated boundaries